# Facebook api reverse loop

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

```
<?php
    require_once("../src/facebook.php");

    $config = array(
            'appId' => '1067257363288184',
            'secret' => '1085551acf0dd68efe5e4b4fd51d88e5',
            'fileUpload' => false, // optional
            'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
        );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user_id) {
        $album_id = '10152679943201541';
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/albums','GET');
        $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos?limit=500");
        echo "Welcome, " . $user_profile['name'] . "&nbsp;<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/picture\" height=\"32\" width=\"32\" />&nbsp;";
        foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
    {

        echo "<li><a href='{$photo['source']}'><img src='{$photo['source']}' /></a></li>";

    }
    }   
     else {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos')); 

        }
    ?>
```

Hi, as my project need to display the latest photos from the facebook album first, but using this loop can only allow me to display the oldest photos since the oldest photos is the first photo in the album. So can anyone help me to display the lastest photos first which is is the last photos in the facebook album.

Comment: Use array_reverse before looping

Comment: I really wonder why a `sort`/`orderby` option isn't available in the facebook API.

Comment: So how do I use a array_reverse for facebook api? =( sorry I am new to php therefore I hope somebody can help me with this. Thank you.